# filtered and non-filtered elements in a single pass

Tags: python, functional-programming

Filter function returns a sublist of elements which return true for a given function. Is it possible to get the list of elements which return false in a different list without going over the entire list again.

Example:

`trueList,falseList = someFunc(trueOrFalseFunc,list)`

PS :  I know it can be done by initializing two empty lists and appending elements to each based on the return value of the function. The list under consideration can be potentially very huge and there might very few elements that might return true. As the append function is costly, is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to write `someFunc` on your own :) The stdlib doesn't have anything like this built in, as it doesn't work well with generators (you can't easily return two generators from a function that operate on the same context).

Comment: i should have mentioned that I was looking for a one liner..i know it can be done via for loop and append but I am concerned about the time for append operation on each element.

Comment: One liners are not necessarily faster and they may be slower. Go for 'easy to understand' over 'shorter so it must be faster' thinking!

Comment: @Graddy: You contradict yourself. First you say you want a one-liner (which is silly, because the problem is too complex to be put into one line without forcing it). Then you say that *performance* is the important point.

Comment: @Graddy: What do you mean "worried about the time for append operation" - how else would those lists be constructed if not by appending the filtered items to the result lists? The fact that you don't have to *write* `.append()` in a list comprehension doesn't mean that the operation doesn't happen.

Comment: how about two different generators ? @Nikals can you explain why it is difficult to return two generators..and what makes it complex if it is not possible

Comment: @Graddy: Please look at my very first comment. Either the generators would need to iterate through the list separately, or they'd need shared state, which gets *very* tricky if your are not iterating them at the same speed (you'd have to keep track of the *difference* list between the two readers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, using iterators:

```
from itertools import tee

def partition(lst, pred):
    l1, l2 = tee((pred(e), e) for e in lst)
    return (x for cond, x in l1 if cond), (x for cond, x in l2 if not cond)
```

Use it like this, and remember that the values returned are *iterators*:

```
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
evens, odds = partition(lst, lambda x: x%2 == 0)
```

If you need lists for some reason, then do this:

```
list(evens)
> [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
list(odds)
> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: This is especially convenient if an inexhaustible generator is used (like `lst = itertools.count()`). +1

Comment: This solution have quite big memory footprint.

Comment: @Trismegistos not that much really, it's using generators all over the place.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez but after you evaluate first returned iterator you will have copy of whole list in memory. Because you evaluated first return value you have to evaluate l1 iterator and to do this you will have to evaluate tee(...) expresion and until l2 is evaluated you will have to hold whole list [pred(e), e) for e in lst] in memory otherwise you would not be able to evaluate l2 -- (pred(e), e) for e in lst) become list because it was created when l1 was evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

```
def someFunc(trueorfalsefunc, l):
    trueList = []
    falseList = []
    for item in l:
        if trueorfalsefunc(item):
            trueList.append(item)
        else:
            falseList.append(item)
    return trueList, falseList
```

So, for example:

```
>>> someFunc(bool, [1,2,0,"", "a"])
([1, 2, 'a'], [0, ''])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go for a one liner you can do this: (I'm switching from dicts to lists as Niklas B. suggested to improve readability)

```
>>> some_list=[True, False, True, False, False]
>>> reduce(lambda (true,false),x: (true + [x], false) if x else (true, false + [x]), some_list, ([],[]))
([True, True], [False, False, False])
```

Comment: ahaha I can do better wait a sec.

Comment: Why the heck do you use a dictionary instead of a tuple? This would be a lot simpler otherwise.

Comment: That's what I meant: `reduce(lambda (true,false),x: (true + [x], false) if func(x) else (true, false + [x]), lst, ([],[]))`

Comment: @NiklasB. well I don't know.. dictionaries came to my mind first! it's not that different in the end

Comment: But it's a *lot* more readable because you can make use of pattern matching.

Comment: @NiklasB. well okay! The edit is more readable, but creates a [None]*5 list for free.

Comment: @luke14free: Of course, because it's borked. Don't use map with side effects. Use a `for` loop instead (so you end up with Tim's code)

Comment: @luke14free: No, it's the exact same thing. You should just use an explicit for loop instead.

Comment: @NiklasB. Of course, I'm aware of that, it's just nonsense one liner code. Not that it could be ever used in production or that anyone could ever think about using it seriously.

Comment: @NiklasB. Yes I definitely agree, I am removing them before that anyone uses them anywhere; and I'm also editing the first one to make it use the lists as you proposed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use generator comprehensions, which should help on performance and facilitate cleaner code. I really am not sure if this will be satisfactory for the rest of your program though. It depends on how you're using these returned results.

```
trueList = (elem for elem in list if trueOrFalseFunc(elem) )
falseList = (elem for elem in list if elem not in trueList )
```

Comment: That's certainly true. I was looking for a compromise between concise code and performance. The single-pass for-loop, in my view, is all-performance, meanwhile two list comprehensions is all-concise. I was thinking this is a bit in the middle, which may be useful in some contexts. Especially if you did not need anything in falseList until after processing everything in trueList. In fact, in that case you'd probably be better off writing a set subtraction function to use on the original list and the ultimate result of trueList.